# Error in a simple java programm

Tags: java

I am trying to convert strings to capital letters and back.
However I'm not receiving the expected output.

```
class Exam4{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws java.io.IOException{
        char ch;
        int changes = 0;

        System.out.println("Enter a period to stop");

        do{
            ch = (char) System.in.read();
            if (ch >= 'a' & ch <= 'z') {
                ch -= 32;
                changes++;
                System.out.println("ch");
            }else if (ch >= 'A' & ch <= 'Z') {
                ch+=32;
                changes++;
                System.out.println("ch");
            }
        }while(ch != '.');

        System.out.println("changes:" + changes);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear.
Also for future questions, it is better to simply copy and paste the code into the post and format is as code.
As for your error, if you want to print a variable you do that without the double quotes. so just `System.out.print(ch);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should say

```
System.out.println(ch);
```

to print out the value of ch, instead of

```
System.out.println("ch");
```

You can also say

```
ch = Character.toUpperCase(ch);
```

to convert a character to uppercase, by the way.